# why 2 objects of Integer class in Java cannot be equal

Tags: java, class, object, integer, increment

my code is:

```
public class Box
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     Integer z = new Integer(43);
     z++;

     Integer h = new Integer(44);

     System.out.println("z == h -> " + (h == z ));
  }
}
```

Output:-

```
z == h -> false
```

why the output is false when the values of both the objects is equal?

Is there any other way in which we can make the objects equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compare two different object and not their values. z and h points to two different Integer object which hold same value.

```
z == h
```

Will check if two objects are equal. So it will return false.

If you want to compare values stored by Integer object use `equals` method.

---

```
Integer z = new Integer(43);   // Object1  is created with value as 43.
z++;                           // Now object1 holds 44.

Integer h = new Integer(44); // Object2 is created with value as 44.
```

So at the end we have two different Integer object ie object1 and object2 with value as 44. 
Now

```
z = h
```

This will check if objects pointed by z and h is same. ie `object1 == object2`
which is false.
If you do

```
Integer z = new Integer(43);   // Object1  is created with value as 43.
z++;                           // Now object1 holds 44. Z pointing to Object1

Integer h = z;                 // Now h is pointing to same object as z.
```

Now

```
z == h
```

will return true.

This might help http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-whats-the-difference-between-equals-and/

Comment: i got to know that == checks for the equality of the references of the object to be equal. So can u tell me how can i make the references equal in this case?

Comment: @HimanshuAggarwal: Reference will be equal if both reference variable are pointing to same object. You want to compare values or reference?

Comment: @HimanshuAggarwal: I have updated my answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 6):

No.  Use `h.equals(z)` instead of `h == z` to get the equality behavior you expect.

Answer (score 3):

`h == z` would work only if you assign the value via auto-boxing (i.e `Integer a = 43`) and the value is in between -128 and 127 (cached values), i.e:

```
 Integer a = 44;
 Integer b = 44;

 System.out.println("a == b -> " + (a == b));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
a == b -> true
```

---

If the value is out of the range `[-128, 127]`, then it returns `false`

```
 Integer a = 1000;
 Integer b = 1000;

 System.out.println("a == b -> " + (a == b));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
a == b -> false
```

---

However, the right way to compare two objects is to use `Integer.equals()` method.

Answer (score 2):

`Integer` is Object not primitive (int) And Object equality compare with `equals` method.

When you do `z == h` it will not unbox into `int` value unless it checks both `Integer` reference(z & h) are referring same reference or not.

As it is derived in [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) -

> The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is an
>   Integer object that contains the same int value as this object.

```
System.out.println("z == h -> " + h.equals( z));
```

It will print `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Integer is an object, not a primitive. If z & h were primitives, == would work just fine. When dealing with objects, the == operator doesn't check for equality; it checks if the two references point to the same object.

As such, use `z.equals(h);` or `h.equals(z);` These should return true.

Comment: so in this case how we can make the references to point the same object?

Answer (score 1):

Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Integer is Object you compare address/references/pointers of objects not values.

```
Integer a = Integer(1);
Integer b = Integer(1);

a == b; // false
a.compareTo(b); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

check to make sure you can use z++ on the Integer object.

Comment: Yeah it can be done. That is called unboxing Integer into an int.

Comment: alright, it's been a while since i've used Java, I know it can be done with an int.