# Integer comparison confusion

Tags: java

Can anyone explain why the o/p is like this for the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

            Integer i1=127;
            Integer i2=127;
            Integer i3=128;
            Integer i4=128;

            System.out.println(i1==i2);
            System.out.println(i3==i4);
 }
```

O/p

```
true
false
```

Comment: use equals() to compare

Comment: See this. It might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786014/why-2-objects-of-integer-class-in-java-cannot-be-equal

Comment: Thanks for the answer.That was helpful.Just checked the java.lang.Integer class and saw a inner class named IntegerCache which has the cache logic implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values from `-128 to 127` for int are cached for boxing. That's why the first comparison returns `true`.

http://www.mohawksoft.org/?q=node/70